# How do I change the primary DNS address of my DSL connection in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager, dns, opendns

I am using a DSL network connection in my Ubuntu 14.04. There has been set up a primary DNS address of my ISP by default. But I want to use Google Public DNS. I tried to edit the connection by going to `Edit Connections->Then Choose my DSL connection->IPv4 Settings->Method:Automatic (PPPoE)->Additional DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8` and saved.
After that I checked Connection Information and found that my Primary DNS is same as before and in the Secondary DNS field there is 8.8.8.8. That means my Primary DNS has not changed and my connection is not using the DNS.

So how do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the option

```
Automatic (PPPoE) - addresses only
```

instead of `Automatic (PPPoE)`. The box will then become just `DNS Servers` instead of `Additional DNS Servers`.

[image: nm-connection-editor:PPPoE]

Comment: Thank you. I changed as you said. But it seems that my DNS cant resolve the connection.

Comment: @AbdullahAlImran IMHO you should post that as a new question (something like *"PPPoE name resolution fails after changing primary DNS server"*), linking to this one and giving as much information as you can about the exact symptoms (e.g. can you ping the chosen DNS server 8.8.8.8? what does `dig google.com` say?)